# Problem with removing array containing objects at specific index

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, splice

My state has shipments array of objects:

```
shipments: [
        {
            containerSize: '',
            numberOfContainer: '',
            grossWeight: '',
            grossWeightUnit: '',
            dimension: '',
            dimensionUnit: '',
            commodityType: '',
            commodity: '',
            temperature: '',
            temperatureUnit: ''
        }
        ],



my function to remove:
removeField = (e, idx) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(idx);
        console.log(this.state.shipments);
        console.log(this.state.shipments[idx]);
        let removedArray = [ ...this.state.shipments ];
        console.log(removedArray);
        removedArray.splice(idx, 1);
        this.setState({
            shipments: removedArray
        });
    };
```

And I want to remove a specific object using splice function 
`splice(id,1)`. But it is always removing last object.

Comment: if its removing always the last object its implies that your idx is wrong. Can you ouput the log of your console.log ?

Comment: idx is index of array ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `reject` from lodash :

```
import {reject} from 'lodash';

const newShipment =  reject(shipments, (item,index) => {
  return index === myIndex; // some condition here
});
```